# Most efficient way to output SQL table  to XML file

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have server that needs to process and dump from an SQL database queries and tables into xml format on disk. This needs to be a scheduled task.

Currently using BCP via a scheduled batch file > sql script > xp_cmdshell >bcp, but this error

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Warning: Server data (172885 bytes) exceeds host-file field length (65535 bytes) for field (1). Use prefix length, termination string, or a larger host-file field size. Truncation cannot occur 
>   for BCP output files.

is troubling me in the log files. I have found no solution online yet. I do not quite understand what the 'host-file field' is referring to. The original table has no column with a value as large as 172885 bytes. The output files are very large, and so far it seems as thought the data is all being written, but there seems to be some garbage at the end of all the xml files.

Performance is important but reliability is the most important for me in this situation.

I have tried recreating the error locally but have been unsuccessful in doing so. The server runs Windows Server 2008 r2.

Any help or explanation/analysis of the error and it's meaning, as well as a recommendation of a simple scheduled solution to dump the sql tables/queries to xml files, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the `FOR XML PATH` syntax introduced in SQL Server 2005:

- [SQL Server: simple example of creating XML file with T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/)
- [What's new in FOR XML in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137.aspx)

With this, you can easily create fairly nifty XML outputs, including hierarchies, attributes and more

Comment: I missed some detail in the question, the issue is not getting my tables/queries to xml, as I am currently using the FOR XML syntax to get to xml data, but the trouble (and error) I believe to be from the solution used to dump the xml data to a file. So I'm more looking to understand the error in my question, and find solutions for creating xml files on disk.

Comment: @Vort3x: well, could you wrap the call to your `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` into e.g. a .NET app or something that would create the file on disk for you?